# how do you find a word in a sentence and return its positions in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

For example "my walked her dog down to the lake which my dog jumped in" i would like the programme to tell me the positions like positions 4 and 11 in my example

Comment: I think this link may be helpful - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I think this link would be useful: [Ask]; also [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

This function should work:

```
Private Function FindWord(Text As String, Word As String) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim results As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim target As String = Word.ToLower
    Dim p() As String = Split(Text.ToLower, " ")
    For i As Integer = 0 To p.Length - 1
        If p(i).Contains(target) Then results.Add(i + 1)
    Next
    Return results
End Function
```

It parses the input into an array of "words". It then uses the contains function to deal with punctuation.

You can call it like this:

```
Dim r As List(Of Integer) = FindWord("my walked her dog down to the lake which my dog jumped in", "dog")
```

You have to consider what happens if the string contains doghouse. If you don't want to hit on that, then this will have to be modified. In that case, you will want to filter out the punctuation and look for an exact match on the rest.

```
Private Function FindWord(Text As String, Word As String) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim results As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim target As String = Word.ToLower
    Dim rgx As New Regex("[^a-z]")
    Dim p() As String = Split(Text.ToLower, " ")
    For i As Integer = 0 To p.Length - 1
        If rgx.Replace(p(i), "") = target Then results.Add(i + 1)
    Next
    Return results
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String.IndexOf

[String.IndexOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx)

You can also use the [VB InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47d6yh63.aspx)